# Получить три случайных числа без повторов и проверки из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

задача: получить 3 рандомных числа от 0 до 49 без повторов
как я вижу выполнение: получить первое число:

```
import random
random_number = random.randint(0,49)
#do something
```

далее добавляем первое случайное число в список, получаем второе случайное число, проверяем- если его нет в списке то ок, если есть- получаем еще раз итд.
Работать будет, но мне кажется в дзене Python есть решение проще и короче, просьба подсказать

Comment: не совсем то что я хотел, но тоже пойдет. я хотел без циклов и без списков чтобы в одной и той же переменной трижды определялись разные рандомные числа. в random.sample придется использовать цикл

Comment: `random.sample(range(50), k=3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Да, в Python есть функция sample из модуля random, которая выбирает случайное подмножество элементов из данной коллекции.

Вы можете сгенерировать список чисел от 0 до 49, а затем вызвать random.sample, указав количество чисел, которое нужно выбрать (3 в данном случае). Это будет быстрее и компактнее, чем использовать цикл.

Пример:

```
import random

# сгенерируем список чисел от 0 до 49
numbers = list(range(50))

# выберем три случайных числа из этого списка
selected_numbers = random.sample(numbers, k=3)

print(selected_numbers)
```

Также можно использовать функцию shuffle из того же модуля, чтобы перемешать элементы списка и взять первые три. Это также будет работать, но будет работать немного медленнее.

Пример:

```
import random

# сгенерируем список чисел от 0 до 49
numbers = list(range(50))

# перемешаем элементы списка
random.shuffle(numbers)
```

Оба способа гарантируют, что выбранные числа будут уникальными и будут случайным образом выбраны из указанного диапазона.

Comment: Что то я сомневаюсь, что генерация 50 чисел с последующей выборкой из них будет быстрее, чем цикл генерации с проверкой для 3-х чисел

Comment: @avp, `random.sample(range(50), k=3)` работает как раз как вам хочется: не строит список, хранит множество отобранных индексов и сверяется с ним ([код](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py#L437-L444)). Вызов `list` не нужен и вреден.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, `set()` в коде немного смущает, но ведь не на ассемблере же (или Си, который можно рассматривать как макроассемблер с типами) пишем

Comment: @avp, на выборке размера три `set` мало будет отличаться по производительности от списка с линейным просмотром. `set` делается от индексов. В Питоне небольшое целое равно своему хешу. Получаем `set` в котором корзины индексируются по самим элементам. Накладные расходы минимальны. Может быть одно лишнее разыменование на элемент.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, если уж говорить об эффективности на микроуровне, то эффективный алгоритм будет использовать 3 регистра в качестве рабочей версии массива из 3-х элементов. На первой стадии unrolling-а будем сравнивать новый rand с одним регистром, а на второй с двумя. Потом запишем их все в память. Вряд ли интерпретатор питона способен увидев `set` произвести подобный код (я предполагаю вариант с JIT компиляцией в native)

Comment: @avp, сам генератор в Питоне тоже не за пару тактов новое значение выдаёт ([os.urandom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom)). На этом фоне операции с `set` не сильно меняют картину.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57190336/7286264) пишут, что в /dev/urandom лезет SystemRandom() (а в вопросе используется Random(), который вызывает [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister)  library function implemented in C). (но в принципе согласен, время генерации random в этой задаче надо учитывать)

Answer (score 0):

Вот простой способ:

```
from random import randint as rnd

list_of_nums = list()
for run in range(3):
    while True:
        r = rnd(0, 49)
        if r not in list_of_num:
            list_of_nums.append(r)
```